# Zip file using C program

Tags: c, zip

Is there any option to zip the file using C programme without using any external application (like Zip..)?

Answer (score 11):

Of course, try using [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). Or [other](http://bcl.comli.eu/) libraries for compression. You can also code the compression algorithm yourself, but that might be too time consuming. Since you did not specify why do you need this, i can't give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the [link](http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/compression.shtml) for some of the compression libraries available. It depends on the system you are using and the features you want. [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) is one which i would recommend because of the configurable features and user manual.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked 7-zip. It has a complete SDK, with example sources, and a lot of functionality. It is Open-source, and free :)
Take a look [here](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)

A good wrapper around it is [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/). 
Sample usage:

```
    SevenZipCompressor compressor;
    compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
    compressor.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Ultra;
    compressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma;
    compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
    compressor.CompressFiles(archiveName, files2Add.ToArray());
```