# zip file I am trying to take an input file and compress the letters.

Tags: c, function, zip

The problem is that I don't know how to call a function. I just need to compress letters into the amount of the letter there is and the letter example. for example aaaaa= 5a

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

zip(zipp);
FILE *ifp;

int main(){

int i,trials, num=0;
char zipp[30000], read[30000];
ifp=fopen("zip.txt","r");

fscanf(ifp, "%d", &trials);

for(i=0; trials>0; trials--){
    for(i=0; read[i]!="\n";i++){
        fscanf(ifp,"%c", read[i]);
        num++;

    }

    zip[30000]=zip(read[i]);
 }



 }

 int zip(i,num){


    for(i=0;num>0;i++){
        num--;

   }




  }
```

Comment: I can see some logial error here: `fscanf(ifp,"%c", read[i]);`, and what is this: `read[i]!="\n"`

Comment: There are so many basic C errors in your program, read some good book for C first then try doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make your code error free..lots of error in your code

- `zip[30000]=zip(read[i]);` which is wrong your array name should be
  `zipp` i think as per your declaration. Also why you assign value on
  fix index `30000`. I not getting you.
- Also declared your function `zip` properly like `int zip(int i,int num)`.
- Most important thing is how you `zip` your latter. i don't see any logic here.look some link and try like [Zip file using C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244082/zip-file-using-c-program?rq=1)

And and for this, i think you revise it again because `read[i]!="\n"` is checked first then taking input to it.

```
 for(i=0; read[i]!="\n";i++){
        fscanf(ifp,"%c", read[i]);
        num++;
```